# RecursionError is limiting my sort function in big arrays

Tags: python, recursion

I need help rewriting some recursion code so I don't run into this error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

My algorithm is supposed to take an array full of random integers and sort them by flipping the integers. Then it returns the amount of flips it took. It works fine until I get around the size of 2^10.

```
def flippers(A, count = 0):
    for i in range(1,len(A)):

        j=i-1
        if(A[j]>A[j+1]):
            temp = A[j+1]
            A[j+1] = A[j]
            A[j] = temp
            j += 1
            count += 1
    for i in range(1,len(A)):
        if(A[i]<A[i-1]):
            return flippers(A, count)
    return count
```

I know it's not perfect and I can probably write the code a lot better. Once my arrays get into the size of 2^10, I get the error above. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to do this in recursion? Because this is a classic task for nested 2-d loop, not recursion.

Comment: I guess not! I just thought we had to. I guess whatever is more simple.

Comment: I think I was trying to do it with a nested for loop but couldn't remember how and some tutorials online kept giving me errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no need of recursion, this is the most simple sorting algorithm:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
        if a[j] < a[i]:
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
```

Also notice that in python, there is no need to use `temp` to switch between 2 variables, and you can simply use `a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]`

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much! I don't know why I was over thinking it so much.